# Differential equations of homogenous type

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My question is :

> $$ (y^3-2x^2y)dx+(2xy^2-x^3)dy=0.$$
>
> Prove $xyrt(y^2-x^2)$ is a const.

I attempted this question keeping y=vx and ended up with $-logv+log (rt((1+v)/(1-v)))=3logx+c $.
From here how to proceed for my answer.

Comment: What is xyrt ?????

Comment: From my answer : $\quad$ xyrt$=(xy)^2$.  This wasn't obvious !

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks I understand now with your answer what op meant

Comment: rt here implies 'root over'/'square root' and not the'whole square '.Can someone make this correction in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$ (y^3-2x^2y)dx+(2xy^2-x^3)dy=0.$$
$y(x)=xv(x)\quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{x^3v^3-2x^2xv}{2xx^2v^2-x^3}=\frac{-v^3+2v}{2v^2-1}$

$x\frac{dv}{dx}=-v+\frac{-v^3+2v}{2v^2-1}=\frac{-3v^3+3v}{2v^2-1}$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{2v^2-1}{-3v^3+3v}dv\quad\to\quad \ln|x|=\int \frac{2v^2-1}{-3v^3+3v}dv= -\frac{1}{3}\ln|v|-\frac{1}{6}\ln|v^2-1|+$constant.

$6\ln|x|+2\ln|v|+\ln|v^2-1|=$constant$\quad\to\quad x^6v^2(v^2-1)=c\quad\to\quad x^6\frac{y^2}{x^2}-(\frac{y^2}{x^2}-1)=c$
$$x^2y^2(y^2-x^2)=c$$